# Resize (Expand) vmware vm disk size

Tags: vmware, disk

Is there a way to resize the disk size i.e., expand the disk size of a VM using govmomi package. Pyvmomi has the  ExtendVirtualDisk(), is there a similar functionality present in govmomi

Answer (score 0):

The same method exists with govmomi as well, see line 1790: https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/blob/master/simulator/esx/task_manager.go

```
&types.ElementDescription{
        Description: types.Description{
            Label:   "Extend virtual disk",
            Summary: "Expand the capacity of a virtual disk to the new capacity",
        },
        Key: "VirtualDiskManager.extendVirtualDisk",
}
```

Comment: The implementation is supposed to be present in the following file, if I am not mistaken?
https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/blob/master/object/virtual_disk_manager.go

However, I do not see any function for extending Virtual disk size.